# typewriter animation not centering text on mobile

Tags: css

It is centered fine on desktop, but the animation will start centered on mobile but continues off, past the page to the right. Any recommendations for how to make sure it stays centered on mobile?

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

html{
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body{
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 3.5em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;  
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25); 
}
.line-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;  
    width: 13em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 220%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);    
}

.anim-typewriter{
  animation: typewriter 2.2s steps(20) 0.9s 1 normal both,
             blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(20) 0s 13 normal both;
}
@keyframes typewriter{
  from{width: 0;}
  to{width: 10.9em;}
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
  from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
  to{border-right-color: transparent;}
}
```

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">12345.6789123<span style="color: #27B59D;">/12345</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your problem depends of body padding.

Comment: What do you want to happen on narrower viewports? You've set the font size to 220% and the width of the final text to 10.9em which altogether is wider than narrow devices so  it goes off to the right. Do you perhaps want to set a fontsize to ensure the text is always seen fully on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .line-1 {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```